# Saving pixel color in array Ruby

Tags: ruby, minimagick

I use CarrierWave and MiniMagick for work with images. I upload image. Right now I need to get values of all pixels in image and store them into array

If I use next code it works well

```
def pixelcolor 
@image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)     
return @image.get_pixels[56][34][1] # 56 and 34 - random numbers for row and column
end
```

next code works as well

```
def pixelcolor 
@image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)     
width = @image.width
color = Array.new   
for i in 0..width
  color[i] = i
end
return color
end
```

But if I try to do next code it doesn't work

```
def pixelcolor 
@image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)     
width = @image.width
color = Array.new
for i in 0..width
    color[i] = @image.get_pixels[45][65][0]
end
return color
end
```

As result I need something like this

```
def pixelcolor 
@image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)     
width = @image.width
height = @image.height  
red = Array.new  
green = Array.new
blue = Array.new    
for i in 0..width
    for j in 0..height
      red[i][j] = @image.get_pixels[width][height][0]
      green[i][j] = @image.get_pixels[width][height][1]
      blue[i][j] = @image.get_pixels[width][height][2]
    end
end
return red, green, blue
end
```

Much time ago I have created very similar project in C++ for working with images so I have idea of what do to but not sure how do do it correct in Ruby as I'm new in it

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ – be more specific, please. Do you get an error or some unexpected result?

Comment: I tried color[i][j] and color[[i][j]] and got 2 different errors:
no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
and 
undefined method '[]='
but now it just trying to load page and doing nothing.
P.S. tried to restart server, still the same - just loading

Comment: Remember that `return` is implicit in Ruby's methods, so it's not necessary to specify it unless you're exiting a method early. Additionally, indentation is *very* important: It helps communicate structure and intent. The code here is jumbled up, visually, and it's hard to tell what's intended to be looped, nested, and so on.

Comment: Another thing is that `for` isn't used in Ruby code. There's always a better tool for the job. In your case here consider using [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to transform one array to another. The real strength of Ruby is the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html) module and if you're not making use of those methods you're missing out on a lot of useful tools.

Comment: Can you give some code example please? @tadman

Comment: It'd be easier to give an example if you could explain what was wrong with your last chunk of code there. Does that work? Is it missing something? Are you gettng the wrong results?

Comment: using my last code I get error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing stems from the fact that Ruby doesn't have a concept of "multidimensional arrays", **individual arrays are always one-dimensional**.

You can, however, have **nested** arrays, which are arrays that contain arrays, like `[[], [], []]`.

---

Let's have a look at two particular places:

```
red = Array.new # Note: this could as well be `red = []`
```

So you have assigned `red` a single empty array. Alright. Here's what you do later on:

```
red[i][j] = ...
```

We don't even need the rest of the line, it's visibly broken already.

On the very first iteration `red` is still **an empty array**. Thus, `red[i]` is `nil`, since there's absolutely nothing inside. `nil` does not have array accessors (`[]` and `[]=`), so you'll be getting errors trying to read or write to it as if it were an array.

So you need `red[i]` to be **an actual array**, so you can put data into it. Let's make it happen.

Since you know the size of your arrays in advance, you can just allocate and populate `red` with with arrays of appropriate length immediately:

```
red = Array.new(width) { Array.new(height) }
```

For instance, for `width = 2` and `height = 3` here's the result you'd get:

```
[
  [nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil, nil]
]
```

So now that you have allocated all the cells that you'll need, you can start overwriting the `nil`s with something meaningful.

See [the docs for `Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-c-new) for the various ways to construct an array.

---

#### Careful:

I have used a "blocky" form of `Array.new` for a reason.

Beginners often make a mistake of using a single value to populate the array like so:

```
red = Array.new(width, Array.new(height))
```

While this form has its uses, it won't have the effect that you need: all the entries in `red` will refer to **one and the same array**, so modifying any single row would look as if all of them are modified.

---

Side note: you probably want to swap `width` and `height` in dimensions, since in graphics programs usually deal with arrays of **rows**, not columns. Depends, though. Might not have any effect on your particular problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I understood arrays in Ruby better @D-side